# Is there any way for adding multiple attributes to dynamodb table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, attributes, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I have recently started with Dynamodb and Cloudformation and YAML, trying to understand more about it. Apologies if there is something I didn't get at first place.
Please refer this code attaching for referrence,I am trying to add multiple attribute to a table but not able to do so

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: AWS CFT To Create DynamoDB

Parameters:
  adminID:
    Type: String
    Default: adminId
    Description: adminId info
  adminIdType:
    Type: String
    Default: S
    Description: adminIdType info

  patientID:
    Type: String
    Default: patientID
    Description: patientID info
  patientIdType:
    Type: String
    Default: S
    Description: patientIdType info

  centerName:
    Type: String
    Default: centerName
    Description: centerName info
  centerNameType:
    Type: String
    Default: S
    Description: centerNameType info

  claimNumber:
    Type: String
    Default: claimNumber
    Description: claimNumber info
  claimNumberType:
    Type: String
    Default: S
    Description: claimNumberType

  technicianName:
    Type: String
    Default: technicianName
    Description: technicianName info
  technicianNameType:
    Type: String
    Default: S
    Description: technicianNameType



Resources:
  # creating table "Patient"
  PatientDetails:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: PatientDetails
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: !Ref adminID
          AttributeType: !Ref adminIdType
        - AttributeName: !Ref patientID
          AttributeType: !Ref patientIdType
        - AttributeName: !Ref centerName
          AttributeType: !Ref centerNameType
        - AttributeName: !Ref claimNumber
          AttributeType: !Ref claimNumberType
        - AttributeName: !Ref technicianName
          AttributeType: !Ref technicianNameType


      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: !Ref adminID
          KeyType: HASH
        - AttributeName: !Ref patientID
          KeyType: RANGE
        - AttributeName: !Ref centerName
          KeyType: RANGE
        - AttributeName: !Ref claimNumber
          KeyType: RANGE
        - AttributeName: !Ref technicianName
          KeyType: RANGE

 
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1


  CenterDetails:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: CenterDetails
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: !Ref centerName
          AttributeType: !Ref centerNameType
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: !Ref centerName
          KeyType: HASH
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1

  TechnicianDetails:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: TechnicianDetails
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: !Ref technicianName
          AttributeType: !Ref technicianNameType
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: !Ref technicianName
          KeyType: HASH
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1


Outputs:
  PatientDetails:
    Description: Table Created using this Template
    Value: !Ref PatientDetails
  CenterDetails:
    Value: !Ref CenterDetails
  TechnicianDetails:
    Value: !Ref TechnicianDetails
```

**Error**: 1 validation error detected: Value '[KeySchemaElement(attributeName=adminId, keyType=HASH), KeySchemaElement(attributeName=patientID, keyType=RANGE), KeySchemaElement(attributeName=centerName, keyType=RANGE), KeySchemaElement(attributeName=claimNumber, keyType=RANGE), KeySchemaElement(attributeName=technicianName, keyType=RANGE)]' at 'keySchema' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 2 (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: BOQH7ELVO8A5KT406LKS9QUCO3VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG; Proxy: null)

What I am trying is to create multiple tables + 1st table PatientDetails is not supporting multiple attributes.
How can I achieve this? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can only have one range key (unless you add more GSIs / LSIs). Do you know what a range key is / what it does?

Comment: Hi @luk2302 I have recently started with dynamodb and trying to understand how it works properly. can you help me with the logical format to follow for adding multiple attributes, it will be very appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Add multiple attributes to what? The table in general? No problem, no need to specify them upfront, you can add whatever data you want at runtime. To the key? Not possible. A dynamodb has ONE primary key and optionally ONE range key. You need to read how to design a dynamodb database schema, the schema entirely relies on the access patterns, do you ever want to access a row based on the `centerName`, ....?